# 2007 iMac kernel panics repeatedly

Tags: imac

I have an iMac (24-inch Mid 2007) which has recently had a lot of kernel panics (a screen pops up telling me to reboot). After rebooting the machine several times, the error still comes up. I took it into the Apple Genius Bar, where they ran a few tests and were not able to fix the problem either. They then told me there weren't even authorised to service it anymore!

Is it worth take it into a third part Apple Authorised Service Provided to take a look at it any see what would be needed to repair it? What kind of cost am I looking just to get someone to look at it (a bench fee)?

Comment: Did you tried changing the ram ? (Falty ram can lead to Kernel panics)

Comment: @CSmith You can also try running the Apple hardware test by holding D whilst turning on your Mac. This will show any problems - if all tests go through fine, then it's probably worth having it looked at. I'm not sure of the price though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of causes for kernel panics and a number of things to try, either fixes or diagnostic. Do some googling and read up on Apple Support. Geniuses are not necessarily the final word. Like, did these start with something new - cable, external, software? Update?

As far as bench fees, call around. Any ASP will tell you the cost.